# Why is horizontal scroll bar going far beyond content?

Tags: css, image, header, scroll, width

I am building a blog and have a large header image with the goal of filling the top of the screen (unless on monitor larger than 1500px)- however the scroll bar goes far beyond the header content and displays white space.

When viewed on an Ipad it zooms out and shows the extra space on the side of the content. Why is the width significantly larger than the image?

Here is the site: http://beautyintheweeds.com/

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<div id="container" class="group">
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"><img src="http://theshalomimaginative.com/weeds/wp-    content/themes/journalist/images/longtop.jpg"/></div></div>

div.inner img { position: relative; left:-50%; }
div.outer {width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: visible;}
div.inner {display: inline-block; position:relative; right: -50%;}
```

This code worked to center the header beyond the container and my hope was that it would always fill the top of the screen unless the monitor was too large. Any ideas why it is creating extra scroll space beyond the image?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the divs have to be inside container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pull them out of the container. Move div.outer above div.container in the markup, remove all css for div.outer, div.inner then add a text-align: center; to div.outer and remove div.inner completely.

Answer (score 2):

It's the element with `class="inner"` that takes up the space. It gets its size from the image inside it, but then you use relative positioning to display the image to the left of the element.

If you want to use that method to center the elements, put a div around it all, that has `overflow: hidden;` and no width set so that it uses the default `width: auto` which will make it take up all the available width.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#container {
width: 911px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
padding: 0 0 0 140px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: that is on purpose. I want the image to be that long- and if I make the container that long it aligns on the left and doesn't center the image the way it is now displayed.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pWDrD/

You will see if you increase the width of the fiddle box then the image automatically increases width without having any scroll bar. Do you understand how i did that? Let me know. If not i will explain. Simply put, when you want an image to go to 100% of the monitor then you need to put it into a container with width as 100% and margin auto, not fixed width and no position at all.

Comment: I don't think they want the image to span 100% width. I think they want to know why div.inner is taking up space on the right.

Comment: I tried that but was having trouble with the image either distorting or becoming way to tall. I want a fixed height of 350 px but don't want the picture to distort.

Comment: I could not find div.inner and also, what do you mean by image distorting in this case? The image in the fiddle i provide is always of fixed height(300px) and there is no scroller?

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/iljfvk.jpg Here is the screenshot of what after making some changes in the css the page would look like on small resolution (like ipod and android devices). It may not be accurate but you can get an idea. Image is centered, not distorted in any way and the scroller at the bottom that you see cease to exist.